# Why is my media query min-width not working?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have a h1 with font size that I want to adjust based on the screen width.

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: ${COLOR.blue};

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
`;
```

I tried it on my Pixel 4a and use USB debugging. Running window.screen.width shows 393 and window.screen.height shows 851. But my font size is 2 rem instead of 2.5 rem... I tried `@media only screen and (min-width:600px)` but its also the same
What Im doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Probably you use a wrong sintax. Have you check in your browser control? do you use some js framework like react? if Yes tag the question with the correct language

Answer (score 0):

If  you want your css to implement on `600px` device width or less, then you need to add

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { //your css }`

When you define min-width in `media query` it means it will work in bigger screen than you have mentioned in `media query` and if you want `css` in smaller devices than you should add `max-width` in `media query` which will work in small devices